# i am getting fatal error using mailparse_msg_create function

Tags: php, parsing, email, pecl

i want to parse the email headers and attachments from the dummy email ( i have text files collections). My hosting account is in Bluehost.com. I used pecl mail parse function to parse the header. When i upload the file and execute it is saying

Fatal error: Call to undefined function mailparse_msg_create()...

I asked bluehost guy they are saying pecl is already enabled on server.

How can i solve this issue. Please help me. My English is not good, hope you all will help me.

Answer (score 4):

Just because you have PECL installed doesn't mean you have the correct extension installed.

Answer: You need to install the Mailparse PECL extension. See http://pecl.php.net/package/mailparse

Comment: Did you include require_once('MimeMailParser.class.php');  prior to using the functions?